# How to adjust the width of the headers in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift

As shown in the picture below, I have adjusted the cells inside the table view so there's some space between the cells and the border of the screen. However, the width of the headers still shown as default(the width of the tableview's width).

I don't want to adjust the tableview's width. How can I adjust the width of the header without simply adding padding to the whole tableview?

[image]

Comment: How did you indent the cells? Why can't you do the same for the header view?

Comment: I tried to build a class that inherits from UITableViewHeaderFooterView then I might be able to do the same thing to the headers, but Xcode told me I cannot inherit from UITableViewHeaderFooterView. I tried CGRect as well, but that didn't work, too.

Comment: Read the documentation for `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`: *"You can use this class as-is without subclassing in most cases. If you have custom content to display, create the subviews for your content and add them to the view in the contentView property."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adjusting the header width, just have a subview in the header that has the design you want.

The Header will always extend the full length of the TableView, but you don't need to use all that space if you don't want to.